# Why this ajax script doesn't return any data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm new to using AJAX and I'm still learning.  I've tried to receive the result of a query, but it seems it doesn't work. Ajax sends data, but doesn't receive anything. I've tried to debug with the console, but I don't have any error.

```
<select class="form-control" id="Input_Cli" name="Input_Cli">
    <option disabled selected value> Seleziona il cliente </option>
    <?php
        $results = pg_query($conn, "SELECT piva, nome FROM cliente");
        while($row = pg_fetch_array($results)) { 
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['piva']?>"><?php echo $row['nome']?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
<button type="button" name="invio" id="invio" class="btn btn-info">Inserimento</button>
<p id = "prova"></div>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#invio').click(function(){
            console.log("Request");
            var cli = $('#Input_Cli').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:'getlist.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data:{cli: cli},
                dataType: 'json',
                succes: function(data) {
                    console.log("Response");
                    console.log(data.listino);
                },
                error: function (xhr, error)
                {
                    console.log("Error");
                    console.debug(xhr); 
                    console.debug(error);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $conn = @pg_connect('dbname = documentale user = postgres password=310398mgp');
    if(isset($_POST["cli"]))
    {
        $data1 = $_POST["cli"];
        $query="SELECT * FROM listinocli WHERE cliente = '".$data1."'";
        $result = pg_query($conn, $query);
        while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $data["list"] = $row["listino"];
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

Comment: getlist.php and prova.php (first code) are in the same directory

Comment: [xkcd: Exploits of a Mom](https://www.xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: `succes` should be `success`

Comment: @Andreas on the console i don't see Response, just Request

Comment: If there really is no response then the `error` handler should be invoked with a timeout or something like that.

Comment: Why use `error: function (_xhr_` ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini i've found that online, i don't know if it's correct

Comment: @ManuelGuatto try to delete part of error and change `succes` to `success`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, you were right, thank you very very much

Comment: @Andreas, you were right, thank you very very much